# Background image in div is not taking entire view

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, jsx

I'm working on a e-commerce platform. I've to show `SoldOut` image over the product image if all total count is zero. Here is my css for sold out products.

```css
  &__imageSoldOut {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
    object-fit: cover;

    img {
      object-fit: contain;
      max-width: 70%;
    }

    @media (max-width: $small-screen) {
      height: 210px;
    }
  }
```

I want my product image in the background will cover the entire view just like the left available products, only soldout image shown as overlay, here the green view will be covered by the background image.
Here is my react jsx

```css
        <div
          className="product-list-item__imageSoldOut"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${(product.thumbnail.url &&
              product.thumbnail.url) ||
              "images/no-photo.svg"})`,
          }}
        >
          <img src={soldOutThumb} />
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set backgroundSize (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) to be 100% of height in this case to not skew the image or fill it both width and height wise

```
       <div
          className="product-list-item__imageSoldOut"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${(product.thumbnail.url &&
              product.thumbnail.url) ||
              "images/no-photo.svg"})`,
            backgroundSize: "auto 100%"
          }}
        >
          <img src={soldOutThumb} />
        </div>
```

*backgroundSize: "[width] [height]"*

Comment: This will only work in the case of a `square div`. If its a wide div then the green will appear on left right sides. But in this case this is ok.

Comment: also forgot to mention! if repeat is on then the image will be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSX, remove the `backgroundImage` and use `background` and write the `url()` along with `cover`. The `cover` style will fill the div via zooming on the image and cropping/clipping the overflowing.

In code it should look like this: `background: url() cover`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it `flex:1`  also try`object-fit: fill`